# Run spring batch job from controller

Tags: spring, hibernate, model-view-controller, spring-batch

```
@RestController
@Controller
public class DemandeWebbatchControler {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemandeWebbatchControler.class);

@Autowired
@Qualifier("jobLauncher")
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("demandeJob")
private Job job;

@Autowired
JobExplorer jobExplorer;

@Autowired
DemandeService demandeService;

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;

/*
 * @RequestMapping(value = "/statistiquesCompteurs.xhtml", method =
 * RequestMethod.POST) public String demandeHandle() throws Exception {
 * 
 * try {
 * 
 * JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time",
 * System.currentTimeMillis()) .toJobParameters(); jobLauncher.run(job,
 * jobParameters); } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException e) {
 * logger.info(e.getLocalizedMessage());
 * 
 * } catch (Exception e) { logger.info(e.getLocalizedMessage()); } List<Demande>
 * d = demandeService.listDemande(); return
 * "Done! Check Console Window for more details: " + " " + d;
 * 
 * }
 */

@RequestMapping(value = "jobs/{jobName}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public JobExecutionDto run(@PathVariable String jobName, @Valid @RequestBody JobParam jobParam)
        throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException,
        JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {

    if (!context.containsBean(jobName)) {

        throw new RasterFormatException("Job Not found!");
    }

    Job job = context.getBean(jobName, Job.class);

    JobParameters jobParameters = getJobParameters(jobParam);

    try {
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
        JobExecutionDto result = new JobExecutionDto();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(jobExecution, result);
        return result;
    } catch (org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRestartException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/jobs/executions/{jobExecutionId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public JobExecutionDto process(@PathVariable Long jobExecutionId) {

    JobExecution jobExecution = jobExplorer.getJobExecution(jobExecutionId);
    JobExecutionDto result = new JobExecutionDto();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(jobExecution, result);
    return result;

}

private JobParameters getJobParameters(@Valid @RequestBody JobParam jobParam) {

    Map<String, JobParameter> parametermap = new HashMap<>();
    parametermap.put(BatchConstants.PERIOD_START, new JobParameter(jobParam.getPeriodStart()));
    parametermap.put(BatchConstants.PERIOD_END, new JobParameter(jobParam.getPeriodEnd()));
    return new JobParameters(parametermap);
}

}
```

Error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'demandeWebbatchControler': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jobLauncher'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncher' defined in com.transactis.qpt.parctis.batch.config.IntegrationConfig: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jobLauncher' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: threadPoolTaskExecutor,taskScheduler
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an error creating the default bean `jobLauncher` which requires a task executor, because you have two task executors defined in your application context. You need to add  a `JobLauncher` bean manually and specify which task executor to use (aka resolve the ambiguity of which task executor to inject). For example:

```
@Bean
public JobLauncher jobLauncher(@Qualifier("taskExecutorForBatchJobs") TaskExecutor taskExecutor, JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception {
    SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jobLauncher;
}
```